# Mysterious apps with strange names and no Icons showing up on my iPhone

Tags: ios, applications, screen-time

I was going through Settings app → Screen Time → Always Allowed, and noticed a couple of mysterious entries. I ssed the first ones, you can see them in the pictures, but there are more all throughout the list of apps.

Anybody else got something similar and/or knows what they may be?

I am using an iPhone X running iOS 12.2.

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Those look like failed app installs.  Have you installed test or development apps to this device?  I installed apps on my iPhone to test during development and I have entries like that, too.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I have never been involved with iOS app development. However, I remember using TestFlight a while ago. There was an app that I was using a lot and kept reporting a bunch of bugs, so the developer eventually enrolled me into the TestFlight thing to get the fixes faster. But I don't remember getting any errors when installing apps through TestFlight. Might this be the issue?

Comment: @futz.co Possible. What you can do is, to check if the app(s) in question is/are installed via TestFlight. The apps installed via TestFlight has a Orange colored dot next to it's name below the app icon on the Home Scren.

Comment: @NimeshNeema I no longer have any apps installed via TestFlight. I have checked the previous apps that were installed through TestFlight and they have no orange dots. Also, opening TestFlight presents me with an empty screen with the `No Apps Available to Test` text.

Now I am getting really intrigued. Do you have any other ideas for continuing this investigation? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case they were webpages that I had added to home screen from Safari

[Reference: Apple Discussions](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8597700)

Answer (score 1):

Those aren’t worrisome to me and just indicate you had an iCloud backup that has an application that cannot be resorted from the could. (Or just that the exception / preference elected for that missing app is showing in the settings app in your case.)

Those long identifiers just are the behind the scenes value assigned to the application when the developer made a request to Apple to make a new app. You normally see the localized name of the application once it downloads, but apparently Apple doesn’t save the app name in iCloud backups - just the identifier so that’s what’s left to display.

You can remove those apps from iCloud data or see if you have the applications on a computer backup to re-transfer them back if needed.

I would consider this a bug that Apple might choose to patch, and not something you have a functional defect - just remove the permissions if you are worried. Worst case, the app comes back and you have to re-grant those permissions once you know which app actually needs those permissions.